# Is it valid to call lambda function after it is destroyed?

Tags: c++

Is it valid to call f_ptr() after lambda is destroyed?

```
void (*f_ptr)() = nullptr;

{
    auto lambda = +[](){some_func1(); some_func2(); some_func3();};
    // lambda is casted to function pointer
    f_ptr = lambda;
    // lambda is destroyed ?
}

// call f_ptr valid?
f_ptr();
```

Comment: The lambda object is already destroyed before `f_ptr = lambda;` because it is a temporary in your example (You are storing the result of `+`, not the lambda, in `lambda`.). But what you are doing is fine regardless, because you are not actually using the lambda object in the call to `f_ptr`. That's just a function pointer that you got by conversion from the lambda object. It is not in any way associated to the lambda object. The matter would be different if you had stored a reference to the lambda object itself and tried to call that out-of-lifetime.

Comment: But compiler introduces some anonymous function somewhere
anonymous_func () {
some_func1(); some_func2(); some_func3();
}
Will this anonymous function live forever? I'm afraid that it will be optimised out in some strange way. Won't it?

Comment: *Will this anonymous function live forever?*  It lives even before the program starts.

Comment: @XeenychXeenych Functions don't have lifetimes. They always exist and are callable, for the whole duration of the program.